# Python listen ports in different threads

Tags: python, multithreading, port, listen

I want to create listener to several ports by using `python 3.*` . I have this code inside utils.py

```
def listenPort(port):
    global conn
    conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    conn.bind(("", port ))
    conn.listen(5)
    #now keep talking with the client
    while 1:
        #wait to accept a connection - blocking call
        c, addr = conn.accept()
        print('Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))
```

and it is call from another files

```
socket_thread = threading.Thread(target=utils.listenPort, args=( globals.listenPort_first , ))
socket_thread.start()
```

I worked right in single thread. But now I have following code for multithread:

```
import utils

def start_func1():    
    socket_thread = threading.Thread(target=utils.listenPort, args=( 1998 , ))
    socket_thread.start()
    # do stuff

def start_func2():    
    socket_thread = threading.Thread(target=utils.listenPort, args=( 1999 , ))
    socket_thread.start()
    # do stuff

if __name__ == '__main__':

    first_thread = threading.Thread(target=start_func1)

    second_thread = threading.Thread(target=start_func2)

    first_thread.start()
    second_thread.start()
```

In this case I got error :

```
 Exception in thread Thread-8:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\lib\threading.py", line 740, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python32\lib\threading.py", line 693, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\workspace\daemon-biotrack\utils.py", line 296, in listenPort
    conn.bind(("", port ))
socket.error: [Errno 10048] Обычно разрешается только одно использование адреса сокета (протокол/сетевой адрес/порт)
```

**Usually, only one is allowed to use the socket address (protocol / network address / port)**

does anybody come across the problem ? If you know any solution please share with me. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655053/python-listen-on-two-ports).But it seems, `SocketServer` is depricated .

Comment: Add a `print(port)` before the call to `conn.bind()` - I suspect you are passing `globals.listenPort_first` from more than one thread by mistake. Also, `global conn` is wrong in the multi-threaded case - you want `conn` to be a local or at least a per-thread variable.

Comment: `global con` is indeed the problem. remove that line.

Comment: I deleted `global conn`, after that error is getting only one time. before it was getting mutch time, how many I call `listenPort`

Comment: I can't reproduce this error. Is there something missing out there?